# TextInputEditText to show numeric keyboard but also allow /

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

I've been trying to adapt my `TextInputEditText` which shows a numeric keyboard currently (it has `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` in the xml) to allow input of a `/` character (by clicking a button in the ui that appends a `/` to the `EditText`).

**What I want to achieve: A numeric keyboard & allowed to enter `/` in the `EditText`**

Everything I have tried either doesn't show a numeric keyboard or doesn't allow me to add the `/` to the `EditText`.

Things I've tried:

1. Adding `android:digits="0123456789./"` to the xml

*Result: It's still a numeric input and won't let me `.append("/")`*

2. Setting `android:inputType="text"` in the xml and  the below in the activity's `onCreate()`

```
        input.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {(src, start, end, dst, dstart, dend) -> {
            if(src.toString().matches("[0123456789./]+")){
                return src;
            }
            return "";
        }});
```

*Result: I don't get a numeric keyboard (although I can only enter the characters I need which is good)*

3. `android:inputType="text"` with `android:digits="0123456789./"` as this seems to be suggested quite a few times on various SO answers (and I assume must have worked at some point).

*Result: a non-numeric keyboard (i.e. regular text input keyboard)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `android:inputType` and `android:digits` from the xml and also adding the below to the activity's `onCreate()` seems to do the trick.

```
input.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789./"));
```

*However it's not completely clear to me that this should or will always work - see note below from the docs on `DigitsKeyListener`...*

> As for all implementations of KeyListener, this class is only concerned with hardware keyboards. Software input methods have no obligation to trigger the methods in this class.

Source:  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/DigitsKeyListener